# C++ if condition not checked after goto

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-statements, goto

I'm working on a simplish game (this isn't the whole code, just the bit that I'm having issues with) and I've run into this issue; After the condition is furfilled, it goes back to the start and it offers me to reenter the string, however, whatever I enter, I just get **'Not Valid'**. Does anyone know why? I'm using the **GNU C++ Compiler**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string command;
mainscreen:
    cout << "blab";
getlinething:
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, command);
    if (command == "task")
    {
        goto mainscreen;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Not valid.";
        goto getlinething;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `goto`. It is very confusing to read for anyone else and bad practice.  You should use a `while` loop to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thing is that this is only a subprogram in the complete thing, I was pondering at the idea with goto, but I can't really figure out how to connect the subprograms without using goto, even if i used while.

Comment: @Whealty_ Use std::wstring and wcout and wcin.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow then it can't compile. It reports an error 'no match for operator= operand types are 'wstring' and 'const char [4]'. GNU GCC Compiler

Comment: @Whealty_ Use L"task" and so on that is use prefix L before string literals.

Comment: Nope, tried it with L"task" and it doesn't work. Same issues as described in my comment below.

Comment: Have you actually verified that the code you have posted HERE actually exhibits the behaviour you describe?  If it is occurring with similar code within a larger program, and you leave out relevant code from that other program, nobody can reasonably be expected to help you.

Comment: @Peter I don't know why are you asking that, but yes I have verified that the code posted here has the same issue as the code used in the application.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code with a debug print it shows that each time you read a new command you are loosing the first char of the string. In fact, when I remove your cin.ignore() it works fine.
Also, have a look at this *while* to see if it fits your needs:

```
cout << "blab";
while(1){
    getline(cin, command);
    if(command == "task"){
        cout << "blab";
        getline(cin, command);
    }
    else{
        cout << "Not valid.";
    }

}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Using g++ in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purpose at least, why not do

```
cout << "'" << command << "' Not valid" << endl ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I tested it out. Without cin.ignore(), I cannot enter the data into the string at all.
The first time I enter it captures everything. So if I wrote task, the string would say 'task', however the second time I entered it, it would say 'ask'. I don't really know why it's doing that.

Answer (score 0):

The `cin.ignore()` line will always discard one character by default (unless it encounters `EOF`, which would be a fairly deliberate act on `cin`).

So, let's say the user enters `task` and then hits the enter key.   The `cin.ignore()` will discard the `'t'`, and the `command` string will contain `"ask"`.      If you want to get a match, the first time through, the user will need to enter `ttask`.   The newline will be discarded, in either case.  The same will happen until a match is encountered.

Comment: I'm not really sure, because the first time I enter 'task' it goes through, and the string says 'task'